# Is UrlHelper.Action Equivalent to UrlHelper.RouteUrl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, urlhelper

I want to replace all instances of [UrlHelper.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) with [UrlHelper.RouteUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx) in my code because of the [performance benefits](https://www.slideshare.net/rudib/aspnet-mvc-performance). According to the documentation, both methods will generate a fully qualified URL, I want to confirm that they will return the *exact* same URL.

---

**Example:**

Assuming that the routes in `RouteConfig` have unique `controller`, `action` combinations:

Given the following route in `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RouteName",
    "Url",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
);
```

Is it safe to assume that

```
urlHelper.Action("Action", "Controller", routeValueDictionary);
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
urlHelper.RouteUrl("RouteName", routeValueDictionary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once there are no routes mapped above your displayed mapping that can match the route generated from

```
urlHelper.Action("Action", "Controller", routeValueDictionary);
```

then you would be safe in your assumption in using the route name.

if for example you have two routes defined like this...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AnotherRouteName",
    "{controller}/blah/{action}",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "RouteName",
    "Url",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
);
```

...then the first route would be matched by..

```
urlHelper.Action("Action", "Controller", routeValueDictionary);
```

UPDATE:

if you look at the source for [UrlHelper](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/UrlHelper.cs)

You will notice that internally they are calling the same overloads of the same methods with relevant arguments.

```
public virtual string Action(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
{
    return GenerateUrl(null /* routeName */, actionName, controllerName, TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionary(routeValues));
}

public virtual string Action(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    return GenerateUrl(null /* routeName */, actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
}

//...other code removed for brevity

public virtual string RouteUrl(string routeName, object routeValues, string protocol)
{
    return GenerateUrl(routeName, null /* actionName */, null /* controllerName */, protocol, null /* hostName */, null /* fragment */, TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionary(routeValues), RouteCollection, RequestContext, false /* includeImplicitMvcValues */);
}
```

Way too much code to post here. take a look at the class source to get a better understanding of what is happening under the hood.

Can't provide any more detail than that. I've gone all the way back to the source code.

Comment: True, so assuming that my routes have unique `controller` and `action` combos, would `Action` and `RouteUrl` be exactly equivalent?

Comment: provided they have the same route values

Answer (score 0):

No, not exactly.

`urlHelper.RouteUrl` only adds an additional filter to the route. You still must provide matching parameters (including `controller` and `action`) or it will return `null` instead of the URL you are expecting.

```
urlHelper.RouteUrl("RouteName", 
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action"[, other route values... ]);
```

The primary difference is that this filter will only make the routing framework check *one* route instead of all of the routes in order. This makes it impossible to match the wrong route when generating URLs, but it is still possible that incoming requests can match the wrong route by putting them in the route table in the wrong order - meaning you can potentially generate URLs from the route table that cannot actually be accessed in the application.

> Unless you have thousands of routes in your route table, it is unlikely you will see any noticeable performance difference.

It is questionable whether there is any real benefit to this. In fact, both `Action` and `RouteUrl` end up calling the exact same method in the `UrlHelper` to generate the URL. Whether you use `Action` or `RouteUrl` to generate URLs, you should still [make unit tests](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx/) to ensure incoming routes match the route you intended and return the correct set of route values.

`RouteUrl` does have a benefit that `Action` doesn't have - you can pass `null` as the route name (or call an overload without route name), which allows you to pass it a ready-made set of route values without having to explicitly set separate parameters for `controller` and `action`. This makes `RouteUrl` act exactly like `Action`, but makes it more easy to integrate with code that manipulates the route values dynamically.

```
urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeValueDictionary);
```

Comment: `RouteUrl` does have an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl%28System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29) that allows you exclude the `controller` and `action`, but yes it does appear that both generate the same URL, and I'll need to create unit tests to verify this. I'll keep the `null` route name tip handy, thanks.